# Using Googlesheet API V4

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, google-sheets-api

I have tried to do lot of R&D to access private Google spreadsheet data from my android studio application. I am able to get the sign in screen and then pass my credentials to sign in. But after login once I execute code:

```
ValueRange response = this.mService.spreadsheets().values()
                .get(spreadsheetId, range)
                .execute();
```

It keeps on returning null value on screen. 
Can anyone please help me.

I am still a learner in Android app and will appreciate any comments on this.

I can paste any code required to help you help me..

Comment: Code formatting

Comment: what do u mean by code formatting?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check and make sure that you use correct HTTP request syntax. As mentioned in [Method: spreadsheets.values.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/get),

> The URL uses [Google API HTTP annotation](https://github.com/googleapis/googleapis/blob/master/google/api/http.proto) syntax.

Response body, if your request is successful, contains an instance of [ValueRange](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values#ValueRange).

Reading further, `values[]` in the response body refers to the data that was read or to be written. Note that, for input, supported value types are: bool, string, and double. With this, make sure that your data uses only the given supported values.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is fixed. The issue was in the below syntax instead of passing google project I was passing my android project.

```
mService = new com.google.api.services.sheets.v4.Sheets.Builder(
            transport, jsonFactory, credential)
            .setApplicationName("GoogleSheet API")
            .build();
```